# Multiple instances of same variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm using an AJAX call to pull filenames from a database which are then used to populate a carousel with images of the same name.

My web app makes use of tabs which when tapped, reload the AJAX and pull from the database a different set of filenames which then repopulate the carousel.

What I'm finding is when the web app initially loads, the carousel works fine, but if I tap any of the tabs, the carousel begins to function incorrectly, i.e. the first time I tap and then use the carousel the carousel moves by two images at at time, a second tap and the images move three at a time, so on and so forth.

If I check console I can see that following the call, when I click either the left or right arrow in the carousel, it's as if there are two instances of the same variable, or as if both AJAX calls are being called in some way. Image attached to show what I mean.

[image: Console log]

As you can see, following initial load everything is fine, however once any subsequent calls are made it's as if the count from the previous call continues, and a secondary count also starts associated with the new data, or a third or fourth or fifth, dependent on how many calls have been made.

```
$('.tabs-nav li').on('click', function() {
    tabName = $(this).html();
    place = 0;
    products = getProductDetails(selected); //AJAX call
    data = dealWithData(products, place);   //Deferred object that works data
});
```

Comment: While the description of the problem you are facing is quite well done, you should also provide a bit of code, or even better a minimal example so that we can understand better what is happening instead of guessing

Comment: @juvian I've added my `click` handler.

Comment: Looks like you are treating asynchronous calls synchronously, but hard to tell from lack of code.

Comment: My advice for debugging: For every relevant function that has a closure (function in function) have a counter variable on the outside, like `var loadFnCount = window.totalLoadFnCount++`, then `console.log` it on the inside function, so you can tell when an old closure might be referenced in some way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you are having a scoping issue. The easiest way is to have your logic in a closure so your variables get scoped to the particular tab. So instead of something like this:

```
var place,count
$(".tabs").on('click',function(){/*shares same place & count */});
```

it would look like this:

```
$(".tabs").each(function(){
    var place,count
    $(this).on('click',function(){/*each has their own place,count*/});
});
```

Comment: I think you're right. I've added my `click` handler code. Assume this is where the issue lies?

Comment: I think so since in the code you provided every time it is clicked place is set to 0